# I/flutter ( 4348): type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<ProductModel>'

Tags: flutter

```
galleries = json['galleries']
        .map<GalleryModel>((gallery) => GalleryModel.fromJson(gallery))
        .toList();
```

[image]

this foto for type NULL

[image]

I want to request data from API

Comment: How are you fetching galleries? Can you share what an API response looks like?

Comment: Please post code as text, not images

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.